# C++ Single Linked List Insertion?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a insertion method where a parameter is a pointer to the previous node. However my implantation has flaws.

It only works if I insert like `test.insert(n2->_next, 4);`, but this is not the previous pointer? If called like `test.insert(n2, 4);` the node is not inserted?

Can anyone tell me where I got it wrong?

**The methods (part of class LLToolkit):**

```
void insert(Node<t>* &prevPtr, t data)
{
    if (prevPtr == nullptr) return;
        prevPtr->_next = new Node<t>(data, prevPtr->_next);
}
void headInsert(Node<t>* &headPtr, t data)
{
    headPtr = new Node<t>(data, headPtr);
}
```

**Node**

```
template<typename t>
class Node
{
public:
Node()
{
    _next = nullptr;
    _data = data();
}

Node(t data = t(), Node<t>* next = nullptr) : _next(next), _data(data) {}

~Node(){ cout << "delete " << _data << _next << endl; }

   Node<t> *_next;
   t _data;
};
```

**My test:**

```
int main()
{
    LLToolkit<int> test;

    Node<int>* n1 = new Node<int>(1, nullptr);
    Node<int>* n2 = new Node<int>(2, n1);
    Node<int>* n3 = new Node<int>(3, n2);

    test.headInsert(n1, 1);
    test.headInsert(n2, 2);
    test.headInsert(n3, 3);

    // Order is now 3 - 2 - 1

    // Should insert new node after n2
    // Like this 3 - 2 - 4 - 1
    test.insert(n2, 4);  

    return true;
}
```

**Acts like below**

[image]

*Here at the grey mark the new node should be inserted.*

**Should work like below**

[image]

Comment: You should try to hide implentation from interface, do not create new nodes and `headInsert` them, let the function create new nodes as needed, you should only have to push data to your `LLToolkit`

Comment: Yes I realize that, but this is a school assignment and prototypes were given for the class. So I have to implement it as such and test this way. @LogicStuff my bad I ment after node.

Comment: @Mat0 *but this is a school assignment* -- And the teacher didn't use a member initialization list.  That doesn't bode too well for the rest of the course.  Also, why are you  dynamically allocating two nodes to create a single node in the list?  Your `main` function used `new`, and then the function you're calling, you use `new` again.  A good linked list shouldn't make the user of the linked list know anything about "nodes".  The test program should just ask the linked list to insert data -- let the linked list class itself create whatever node it needs to create internally.

Comment: So when `test.headInsert(n1, 1);` is executed it creates a new node with 1 as the `_data` and `_next` as the node n1 (which has `_data = 1, _next = nullptr`) , I am surprised how your print methods are even printing the lists correctly because it doesn't look like `headInsert` is building it correct.

Answer (score 2):

Following your code, you seem to be doing the following.

1. Create a new node with value 1 and a null next pointer.

   ```
   Node<int>* n1 = new Node<int>(1, nullptr);
   ```

   **Result:**

   ```
   n1(=1) -- nullptr
   ```
2. Create a new node with value 2 and a next pointer to `n1`.

   ```
   Node<int>* n2 = new Node<int>(2, n1);
   ```

   **Result:**

   ```
   n2(=2) -- n1(=1) -- nullptr
   ```
3. Create a new node with value 3 and a next pointer to `n2`.

   ```
   Node<int>* n3 = new Node<int>(3, n2);
   ```

   **Result:**

   ```
   n3(=3) -- n2(=2) -- n1(=1) -- nullptr
   ```
4. Creating a new node with value 3, next pointer to `n1`, and changing `n1` to point to the new node instead.

   ```
   test.headInsert(n1, 1);
   ```

   **Result:**

   ```
                      n1(=1)
                        |
                        |
   n3(=3) -- n2(=2) -- nn1(=1) -- nullptr
   ```
5. Doing the same with `n2` and `n3`:

   **Result:**

   ```
   n3(=3)     n2(=2)     n1(=1)
     |           |         |
     |           |         |
   nn3(=3) -- nn2(=2) -- nn1(=1) -- nullptr
   ```
6. Insert 4 after `n2`.

   **Result:**

   ```
   n3(=3)     n2(=2)     n1(=1)
     |           |         |
     |         nn4(=4)     |
     |           |         |
   nn3(=3) -- nn2(=2) -- nn1(=1) -- nullptr
   ```

So the question is, is this really what you want? Sorry if I misunderstood your code, it's kind of hard if I can't compile it here.

Comment: I've added headInsert so you can see how it works. If you look at the console output it's printed like:                                                           [adress of node]  [ data ] [adress of next node].                                       So the pointers are connected